# How is sharp quote (#') different from symbol-function?

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp, sharp-quote

To me these operators seem to do the same thing. Both take a symbol and return the function associated with it. Is there any difference?

`elisp` evaluation returns the following:

> (defun foo (x) (+ 1 x))
>   foo
>    (foo 3)
>   4
>   #'foo

Which I don't understand either.

Furthermore is there a difference between common lisp and elisp? I'm learning from resources on either.

Comment: You may wish to remove the elisp tag from this question -- I don't think you tried this out in Emacs before you asked.

Comment: @phils I don't understand elisp's behavior either, see edit.

Comment: In elisp `function` (`#'`) is largely equivalent to `quote` (`'`) and hence it does *not* return the function definition for a symbol; it just returns the symbol. There are still reasons to use it (historically the benefit was restricted to byte-compilation, and nowadays there are also reasons related to lexical binding), but your specific question title makes very little sense for elisp.

Comment: I go further to suggest you learn one Lisp (at least the basics), perhaps the one that gives you the greatest return in short-term, then learn another.  Learning two Lisps in an early stage and keep comparing them will only confuse you, a lot.  Actually, this fits well for any two similar languages.

Answer (score 7):

**Common Lisp**:

`SYMBOL-FUNCTION` can't retrieve functions from lexically bound functions. `FUNCTION` references the lexically bound function by default. `#'foo` is just a shorter notation for `(FUNCTION foo)`.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defun foo () 'foo)
FOO

CL-USER 2 > (flet ((foo () 'bar))
              (list (funcall (symbol-function 'foo))
                    (funcall #'foo)
                    (funcall (function foo))
                    (eq (function foo) (symbol-function 'foo))))
(FOO BAR BAR NIL)

CL-USER 3 > (eq (function foo) (symbol-function 'foo))
T
```

Answer (score 4):

[Rainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320764/1281433) discusses the things that you can do with **function** that you can't do with **symbol-function**, namely retrieve the value of lexically scoped functions, but there are a few other differences too.

### The special operator FUNCTION

The [special operator FUNCTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm) provides a way to find the functional value of a name in a lexical environment.  Its argument is either a function name or a lambda expression. That **function** can take a lambda expression means that you can write: **(function (lambda (x) (list x x)))**.  The term *function name*  includes more than just symbols.  It also includes lists of the form **(setf *name*)**, which means that you can do things like **(function (setf car))**.

### The accessor SYMBOL-FUNCTION

The accessor [**symbol-function**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm), on the other hand, lets you retrieve and set the functional value of a symbol. Since it requires a symbol, you can't do **(symbol-function (lambda …))** or **(function (setf *name*))**.  **Symbol-function** also  can't see lexical environments;  it only works with global definitions.  E.g.,

```
(flet ((foo () 'result))
  (symbol-function 'foo))
;=> NIL
```

Since **symbol-function** is an *accessor*, you can *change* the value of a function's symbol with it.  E.g.:

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'foo) (lambda () 42))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1005D29AAB}>
CL-USER> (foo)
42
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'foo) (lambda () 26))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1005D75B9B}>
CL-USER> (foo)
26
```

### The accessor FDEFINITION

There's also the [accessor **fdefinition**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm#fdefinition) which is kind of like **symbol-function** in that is can only access globally defined functions, but kind of like **function** in that it can access of symbols and **(setf *name*)** lists.  However, it does not retrieve the value of lambda functions.

Comment: Is there a distinction between a symbol and name? I'm starting to wonder if I understand lexical scope less than I thought.

Comment: @djechlin A symbol is an actual object.  You can inspect it, you can create them with make-symbol, etc.  In source code (as data), symbols occur very frequently.  However, lexical variables, e.g., `x` in `(let ((x 42)) x)`, while represented by symbols in the source code, don't actually have any connection with the symbol at runtime.  The compiled version of `(let ((x 42)) x)` doesn't need to know anything about the symbol `x`.  Intuitively, this makes sense, because we'd expect the code `(let ((y 42)) y)` to compile to the same thing.  (However, when a variable is special, there *is* a

Comment: @djechlin connection with the symbol.)  As to the difference between variable names and symbols: *most* of the time that you need a function name, you'll be interested in something that's a symbol (e.g., `car` or `make-person`).  But lists of the form `(setf <symbol>)` are also function names.  You can do, for instance, `(funcall #'(setf car) ...)`.   See [the glossary entry for *function name*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_name).